# Retrieve data attribute value using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="video cover" data-thumb="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/1234567.webp?mw=700&amp;mh=393" style="background-image: url(https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/525930392.webp?mw=700&amp;mh=393);">
```

I would like to retrieve the `data-thumb` URL value.

I have attempted to retrieve the value using the following:

```
$iframe = '<div class="video cover" data-thumb="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/1234567.webp?mw=700&amp;mh=393" style="background-image: url(https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/525930392.webp?mw=700&amp;mh=393);">';

preg_match('/data-thumb="(.*?)"/', $iframe, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

However, this is not retrieving any matches.

**EDIT: Thank you for your help and answers. It appears I made an error with the output of $iframe, which was displaying content from an iframe (doh). So preg_match couldn't target it.**

Comment: Are you just not receiving any matches?

Comment: I take it `$iframe` is the string containing that HTML?

Comment: yes, I have updated the question..

Comment: Testing on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com), there isn't an issue as far as I can see with the regex. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code you are executing? It seems to be something elsewhere in your code that is actually causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help and answers. It appears I made an error with the output of $iframe, which was displaying content from an iframe (doh). So preg_match couldn't target it.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/data-thumb="([^"]*)"/', $iframe, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1]))
   echo $matches[1]; // echo the value of the data-thumb attribute
```

This works for me. And indeed, original code works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/data-thumb="[\s\S]*?"/
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't retrieve any matches

Comment: Should be `data-thumb="([\s\S]*?)"` to actually get matches.

Comment: Either way, it doesn't seem to be the regex that's causing the issue.

Comment: It does, but i don't think the code he posted causing the 'no matching"-problem. Maybe a syntax or other error is causing the no matching"-problem, since the code works fin on my machine.

Comment: So maybe this is just part of the code and something else unposted is causing the overall issue?

Comment: That's the only thing i can think of :)